# Send json object as url parameter

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, sequelize.js, ngresource

I'm creating an Angular app using ngResource, and i want to send a search/filter/pagination (I am using sequelize as ORM in the backend, and i want to use that object to apply the search, filter and pagination stuf directly) parameter to a GET request, all that in a Json object, there is any way cast this object, or there is a better way to do this.

This is an example of what I want to do

```
rank: {
  $or: {
    $lt: 1000,
    $eq: null
  }
}
```